# Android gradlew assembleRelease --sourcemap output fail because bundle doesn't exist yet

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

When bundling react-native code via `gradlew assembleRelease` and having the generate source maps tag added to the app build.gradle, bundling error occurs.

***"error ENOENT: no such file or directory,
app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.js.map"***

In './android/app/build.gradle', I have the `extraPackagerArgs` property to generate source maps.

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.js.map"]
]
```

### Doesn't work

When calling `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease` in the root of the project folder.

This however fails because it seems as though its trying to generate the source map before the bundle file `index.android.bundle` is even created.

**example:**

- first I clean my project via android studio.
- `\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release` will be empty.
- next, run `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease`.

The error is displayed stating that there is no bundle file as its trying to make a sourcemap.

### Works

**example:**

- clean the project via android studio
- run `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease` **without** having `extraPackagerArgs` in the build.gradle file.
  The bundle is created in ..\intermediates\assets\release.
- Next, add back the `extraPackagerArgs` for generate the sourcemap.
- Run again `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease`, and the sourcemap is created.

This tells me that whatever arguments are added to `extraPackagerArgs` seem to be running before the bundle is actually created.

Does anyone know a way to ensure that the sourcemaps only get generated after the bundle file is made?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution?